# Gson api parsing issue Kotlin

Tags: api, parsing, kotlin, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to parse the JSON returned by the following API call (recipe and ingredientLines only):

```
https://api.edamam.com/search?q=khachapuri&app_id=xxx&app_key=yyy
```

My model for GSON looks like this:

```
class FoodModel {
    var label:String = "Yummy"
    var image:String = "https://agenda.ge/files/khachapuri.jpg"
    var ingredientLines = ""
}
```

After launching the app, I'm facing the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I think I'm writing the model class incorrectly, because the structure of a json is not clear for me. This is how I'm trying to use Gson: `val foodItems = Gson().fromJson(response, Array<FoodModel>::class.java)` can anyone help?

Comment: Could you please post json string which you are trying to parse

Answer (score 0):

The JSON object returned by the API has a slightly different structure compared to your model.

In particular the API is returning a complex object that you need to traverse in order to extract the information you are interest into. A high-level example (I'm not able to test it, but hopefully you'll get the gist of it):

```
data class Response(
        val hits: List<Hit>
)

data class Hit(
        val recipe: Recipe
)

data class Recipe(
        val label: String,
        val image: String
)

val foodItems = Gson().fromJson(response, Response::class.java)
```

Just be aware that Gson may create instances in an unsafe manner, which means you may experience `NullPointerExceptions` thrown apparently with no reason. If you want to prove it, just rename `image` to anything else (you can also try with other fields, it doesn't matter), and you'll see its value is `null` even if the type is non-nullable.